# set the cursor position to left in Edit Text in Android

Tags: android-layout

I want to move the 
**cursor position of `EditText` to the left**
most side. Now the cursor is blinking at the center of `EditText`.

```
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mytext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:lines="5"
            android:textSize="12dp" >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `android:gravity="center"` instead you have to use `android:gravity="left"`